# PowerShell Pipeline Script Block inside Hashtable

Tags: powershell

Hopefully a PowerShell noob question, but how do I access the current pipeline object inside a script block which is also within a hashtable?

Here is what I'm trying to do in its entirety:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Group Name" | 
    Where {$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | 
    Get-ADUser -properties extensionAttribute1 | 
    Where {$_.extensionAttribute1 -ne ($_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com")} | 
    Set-ADUser -replace @{extensionAttribute1=&{$_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com"}}
```

I have everything working except for that last line, where the new `extensionAttribute1` should be generated from the current users `UserPrincipalName`, replacing the domain. Running this code results in an error:

```
+ Set-ADUser <<<<  -replace @{ExtensionAttribute1=&{$_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com"}}
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=Bar\, Fo...ADdomain,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Replacing the code inside the script block with a string works ok (below), so it seems like some sort of access issue to the current pipeline object. Does `$_` not work in this case?

```
Set-ADUser -replace @{extensionAttribute1=&{"foobar"}}
```

Comment: I think what's going on here is that Set-ADUser is accepting a batch of information all at once, and therefore is similar to calling `$MyArrayOfUsers | Set-ADUser...` where the single object in the pipeline is the array, not each user (I'm guessing). If you instead replace the last line with `Foreach-Object {Set-ADUser $_ -replace@{extensionAttribute1=&{$_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com"}}}` does that work? It means lots of individual calls instead of one big call, but I think that should work. I can't test it right now, but let me know if it works.

Comment: @squid808 Yes, that does work. Strange, so is `$_` only valid for some commandlets?

Comment: I think it's more about how you use it, since it represents one value, `this`. I'll throw my musings in an answer so I can be a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer seems to be using a foreach in your pipeline, as such:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Group Name" | 
    Where {$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | 
    Get-ADUser -properties extensionAttribute1 | 
    Where {$_.extensionAttribute1 -ne ($_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com")} | 
    foreach-objct {Set-ADUser $_ -replace @{extensionAttribute1=&{$_.UserPrincipalName -replace "@ADdomain.com", "@GAdomain.com"}}}
```

As for why, I'm pretty sure it's because Set-ADUser only accepts one object, whether it's one ADUser or one collection of ADUsers. Since `$_` represents `this`, the way you had it was causing Set-ADUser to see `$_` as the one object you were providing in the pipeline - the group of users (instead of each individual user).

*Note: The following is speculation! If I'm wrong please correct me!*

Regarding Set-ADUser taking one or more objects... here's my guess. If you look at the Input Types of [Set-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx), it gives the types of `None` or `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`. But as you have seen, you can also pass along a collection of `ADUser` objects and Set-ADUser will accept that as well. From my understanding of that cmdlet, when you call it you can run the same Set command on all objects in that collection. For instance, you could do as you mentioned (assuming $users contains everything in the pipeline up until then):

```
$users | Set-ADUser -replace @{extensionAttribute1=&{"foobar"}}
```

My guess is that under the hood, Set-ADUser is accepting $users as the single parameter value (by setting the [ValueFromPipeline attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipeline%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `true` in the code) and applying the parameters you provided to each object therein. Since the iteration of the collection is happening within the cmdlet's code (which is no longer in PowerShell, it's the compiled .Net code), the `$_` would have no use here in terms of representing each object.

I'm not sure the mechanics of why the pipeline lets you run [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) in a pseudo-foreach fashion since they have the same input types (you called that in a similar manner without using foreach) but based on the evidence, I have to assume it's under the hood. If anyone has further insights, I'm definitely curious to know. I may be totally off base!

Comment: I think the main reason it worked is that you added the positional variable for -Identity.  In this case you set it to `Set-ADUser $_ ...`.  Before that, there was nothing indicating which user to set.

Foreach, or %, can be implied in PS 3 and later, in some situations.  Basically it's overloaded.  The code runs once for each object in the stream.  I can't seem to figure out when you need to explicitly use %{} in the pipeline, so I use it explicitly any time there can be more than one object coming down.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's implied in the pipeline or in the cmdlet's code itself, though. Is the pipeline assuming you want % for the Get-ADUser, or is it just accepting a collection?

Comment: I just write assuming I need the %{} on one-liners.  Since the foreach works if there's only one object, it then becomes consistent.

I also prefer scripts to one-liners complete with comments and functions and formatting for readability.